# How to Approach Resigning With a Current Workplace Injury?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, resignation, canada

I an in a job etiquette and moral quandary, in Ontario.
I have been working on a jobsite. I have been slipping and falling many times a day, and had decided that the job was generally too dangerous for me.

I had recently decided to resign over these concerns. Then, today, I fell ~5 feet off of a work platform onto a small metal poll and can only walk and move with extreme difficulty and pain. I was driven to the Emergency and told by the doctor that she was giving me 2 days off, meaning "go to work on Monday". But the personnel manager phoned me and told me it is really important that I go in tomorrow to start modified duties. At that time I did not raise any concerns (beyond a general doubt that I would physically be able to walk tomorrow) or inform him of what the Doctor told me she was writing down, but I sort of assume he did his due diligence and read the doctor's report.

I don't really feel like it is fair to me to just resign, and be bed ridden for who knows how long without any compensation. But I also simply do not think I can even get into work without hiring a stretcher, and walking on ice seems like a really stupid idea to me. I have 2 paid sick days that I can use.

What is good job etiquette in this situation? How can I approach this while retaining a courteous and respectful relationship between myself and my boss but also not being taken advantage of? What is a fair resolution to this situation?

I don't feel comfortable lying, even lies of omission. I don't think I can get past tomorrow morning without telling him I am resigning. But can I just straight up say? "The doctor said Not to come in till Monday, so I won't be. And if I still feel terrible then I might take a sick day or two. Oh and I am resigning effective Wednesday." (should I mention why I am resigning?)

N.B.
*I got the job for fun and because I wanted to learn a trade. I don't really need to work in the industry again. But I still consider it fun and a important Trade to know*
*I consider all of our exchanges thus far be completely equitable. I knew the risks and took them willingly*

Comment: What country are you in? Laws and customary expectations vary. In England, your employer could be prosecuted regardless of your willingness to take on risk.

Comment: Updated with location. But no one is goign to be prosecuted. I have no interest in that, and the ministry of labour is not omniscient.

Comment: One question: Did you slip all the time and fall 5 feet because you are not able to walk straight, or is it due to missing security that your boss/company should provide? So are all employees excepted to be falling all the time, or is something really wrong there?

Comment: I was not the first to slip and fall that day, nor the first to fall from that work platform. Its rural construction, nothing we do would pass any sort of legal scrutiny. But that is sort of tangent to the question I am trying to ask here.

Comment: Update: I sent an email stating that I could not physically come in for the next two days. And stated that the job was too dangerous for me personally and had come to the decision that I was resigning effective Monday. They phoned and told me that they would give me my two paid sick days, and would accept my resignation for Monday. So I feel like everything was solved equitably, I will be paid for the days that I will be nearly entirely bedridden. And then we part company, and I don't have to go back working in those conditions.

Comment: Sounds like a huge safety issue.  Or OP is accident prone?

Comment: I bet that the company are *really* glad they got away with just paying you off two days pay, after you were injured at their workplace.

Answer (score 5):

### Do not resign until you resolve your workplace injury.

When a Canadian worker is injured on the job he/she is usually eligible for Worker's Compensation.  To learn more about Worker's Compensation in Canada, check out the official website for the Association of Workers' Compensation Boards of Canada - http://awcbc.org/

You also might want to consider contacting the Ontario Office of the Worker's Advisor - http://www.owa.gov.on.ca/Pages/default.aspx  Their office is independent of the Ontario Ministry of Labor, and they provide free and confidential services for "non-union workers who have been injured at work or who have been threatened or punished for following health and safety laws."

> Ontario Office of the Worker's Advisor - Canada-wide Toll Free
>   Telephone
>
> **Workplace insurance issues:**
>
> 1-800-435-8980 (Service in English)
>
> 1-800-661-6365 (Service in French)
>
> 1-866-445-3092 (TTY)
>
> Email: owaweb@ontario.ca
>
> Canada-wide Toll Free: 1-800-660-6769

Answer (score 0):

I think you already said something relevant here:

> But can I just straight up say? "The doctor said Not to come in till Monday, so I won't be. And if I still feel terrible then I might take a sick day or two. Oh and I am resigning effective Wednesday."

**Yes you are in full right to say so**. If the doctor said you should take certain time off then they can't make you work against doctor orders; **have your doctor write this down**, so you have something to back you up. I doubt they will make you work despite doctor's orders, as that may get them into legal trouble.

However, **I suggest you don't drop the "I am quitting" in that same moment.** Otherwise, the moment you are able to go back to work (still sore and aching probably) you are subject of being terminated right there. Best thing to do IMO is to recover, come back to work and *then* discuss about resigning on a more appropriate moment.

You say you don't like lying (even by omission) which is great, but unless directly asked *"Do you plan to quit?"* I don't see how holding this information for a better moment can be a lie. I strongly suggest you try to keep this to yourself until things have calmed down a bit and you have recovered fully.

**Meanwhile I suggest you start looking for other jobs**, as you have better chances of getting a new one while still hired, not to mention the economical hardships you will be sparing yourself if you instead quit and then started looking.

Comment: Per your quote:

I have been slipping and falling many times a day, and had decided that the job was generally too dangerous for me.

This actually scares me from a workplace perspective.  Is this a safe worksite?  Is this something worth getting OSHA involved in?  If so for the sake of your co-workers I'd suggest giving the OSHA Hotline a call and get them inspected if you suspect issues.

Comment: @tekiegreg that would be recommended only if *other coworkers* also slip or fall often. If this is just some unfortunate case that OP is going through (perhaps OP can be more careful or mindful?), then raising such concern may not be wise, as it would only be hassle for all (unnecessary for the company, and even may endanger OP's job or future jobs if he is the only one experiencing this, and is raising issues with OSHA "just because")

Comment: Give the update stating that OP is in Canada, OSHA's counterpart there would be CSA.